# Float to Decimal Conversion in C#

Tags: c#, floating-point, decimal-point

```
int i = 1;        // -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
float f = 2.1f;      // -3.402823e38 to 3.402823e38
long l = 3;       // -922337203685477508 to 922337203685477507
double dbl = 4.5;   // -1.79769313486232e308 to 1.79769313486232e308
decimal dec = 5.2m;  // -79228162514264337593543950335 to 79228162514264337593543950335

dec = i;     // No error
dec = l;     // No error

dec = f;    // Compiler error
dec = dbl;  // Compiler error

f = (float)dec; // No error (May loss precision) ok

**dec = (decimal)dbl;** // No error  why it requires ?
```

Why the above code requires Explicit Cast. 
 Range of float/Double > Decimal ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it isn't just about precision; you need to think about *range* too - and frankly `1.79769313486232e308` is **really, really** large (as in > 300 digits to the left of the decimal place). Your assertion "Even Range of decimal > float or double" is incorrect.

```
var dbl = double.MaxValue;
var dec = (decimal) dbl; // BOOM!
```

The range of a `double` is *larger* than the range of a `decimal`.

Also, you might need to consider `double.NaN`, `double.PositiveInfinity` and `double.NegativeInfinity`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Marc. But same story for the float also ?

Comment: @MSK a `float` still has range x10^38 (which is what e38 means), so YES. Also, `foat.NaN`, `float.PositiveInfinity`, `float.NegativeInfinity`... For comparison, decimal's range is e28

Comment: decimal dec = decimal.MaxValue;
             float flt = (float) dec; // OK  . I assume that, an explicit conversion requires when doing downcast. Range of decimal < float. Why it requires explicit instead of implicit cast.Pls Correct me if i wrong

Comment: @Msk because you are still losing precision. Lots of decimals simply can't be expressed exactly in a float. Even things like (untested) "0.3"

Comment: OK. I need explicit conversion when 1) May Loss of precision or 2)Range is low LHS. I think i'm right.

Comment: @MSK well, the simpler statement would be: you need explicit conversion whenever the spec says you do, or whenever a custom type defines explicit conversion operators

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Conversion depends on the size of the datatype not on the Range of the Datatype.

```
Integral Types

DataType    Size    . Net (CTS) Comments
byte    1   System.Byte 0 - 255 It is Unsigned
sbyte   1   System.SByte    -128 to 127 - Signed
short   2   System.Int16    
ushort  2   System.UInt16   
int     4   System.Int32     
uint    4   System.Unt32    
long    8   System.Int64    
ulong   8   System.UInt64   

Floating Types
decimal 16  System.Decimal  Has up to 28 digits after decimal
float   4   System.Single   Has up to 8 digits after decimal
double  8   System.Double   Has up to 15 digits after decimal
```

Comment: If it depends on Size why it doestnt allow implicit Cast.